# Is there a way to make VS2012 aware that the file I'm working on is to be contained in another file (in terms of markup validation and file pathing)?

Tags: html, validation, visual-studio-2012

I am developing an HTML5 presentation of sorts that loads only one file (index.html) to the browser directly, and all the other "slides" are loaded into that index file through ajax. Is there a way to tell Visual Studio that, "Hey, this file should be treated as though it were in this spot of this other file" so it will stop bugging me about divs needing to be in a body tag and that all my images don't exist (because the filepath is relative to the index file, which is in another folder)?

I tried Googling this, but I really don't know what search terms I would even use...

To clarify, here are the features that I would like to have working (that would be working if VS understood where this file eventually ends up):

-CSS class/id intellisense (from script tag)

-Stop putting red squigglies under my div tags!

-Correct link pathing (to images, files, etc)